# How to make RequiredFieldValidator disappear and then appear?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I want the required  field validator to become only visible whenever there is an error..not all the time.. How can i achieve so?

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
    runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="Editor1"
    ErrorMessage="fffffff"
    ForeColor="#CC0000"
    Display="Dynamic" />
```

The error message appears as soon as I run the page..I want it to appear whenever there is an error..When the field is empty!!

Comment: Can you please elaborate more this statement "I want the required field validator to become only visible whenever there is an error"

Comment: This should help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855015/how-to-make-requiredfieldvalidator-error-message-display-after-click-submit-button

Comment: Maybe this validator is telling you there is some unintended Post attempt going on...  Compare behaviour with that on a clean new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only cause of your problem in your current page is that, in the page Load event, somewhere `Page.Validate()` is called and you need to to check that.

I have tested this sample at my end and the validator is not fired to me at page load.

Can you try this in a separate new Page?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
runat="server"
ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
ErrorMessage="fffffff"
ForeColor="#CC0000"
Display="Dynamic" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

If you check the above mentioned example, it will not fire Validator on page load, but you can add this code, and you will find, the validator is fired on page load..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();
}
```

Please note, I have tested both scenarios on the new page, just try it and you will understand the problem.

Comment: The validator works with no problem, is that its Editor tells it somehow that it is empty....May be I should check the validator dynamically and ignore the requiredfieldvalidator?

Comment: yes, you can. But I would suggest you, that you can check it in JavaScript on Click of button.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, at page load the field is empty...and therefore an error.  Give the requiredfieldvalidator the property of `InitialValue=""` and that should give you what you want.

Comment: It still wont do the trick..thats because the rquiredfieldvalidator watches over editor..which is ajax...Thats why i think it doesnt work on it

Comment: Did you even try the initalvalue or just assume?

Comment: Yeah..I tried..That validator control works with no additional attributes..but only because the Editor control is an ajax control..it makes problems

Answer (score 0):

Set Display Property of required field validator to Dynamic