# asp.net required field validator

Tags: asp.net

A required field validator should fire only after clicking a submit button

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="req" controltovalidate="txtphone" errormessage="please enter the details">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make requiredfieldvalidator error message display after click submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855015/how-to-make-requiredfieldvalidator-error-message-display-after-click-submit-butto)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a button field try by applying `Validation Group` Property in both the validator and Button as follows

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="req" runate="Server" controltovalidate="txtphone" errormessage="please enter the details" ValidationGroup="g">
```

```
<asp:button id="btn" runat="server" validationgroup="g">
```

Answer (score 1):

Youre missing runatserver on your code

Check this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    Phone Number:<br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtphone" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="req" controltovalidate="txtphone" errormessage="Please enter your phone number!" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnSubmitForm" text="Ok" />
</form>
```

Regards